# Is it possible to run Win32 executable on a virtual private server (VPS)?

Tags: php, vps

Is it possible to run Win32 executable on a virtual private server (VPS)?

I have created some .exe application from C++ code, and I need to let people on the internet run it, is it able to do so on a VPS? or I have to rent dedicated server?

I will take input from HTML form, pass it to PHP, and from PHP call 'system' to run my application with command line parameters, then get back the results to PHP, finally return the results to browser as HTML.

Comment: Ah. This should have been closed as "not constructive", not migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know 'VPS' is just a marketing word for a virtual machine, so basically **yes** you can run a Win32 .exe in it, **if** you install a windows system (or a system with Win32 compatibility) in it. To get your program outputs into a php/html interface, you need to run a webserver with php installed inside the vm, too.